# Formula to work out whether all filled in fields are the same, but ignores those that aren't filled?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm trying to work a formula so that a cell reads "Days" if all of the filled in cells in a selection are equal, but ignoring those that equal 0 (or blank, whichever's easier).

I've got a start with all the fields I believe I need (don't have the rep for a screen shot but I'll try and explain)

The sheet is to work out holidays based on hours entered in the "hours" row, with Monday K16, Tuesday L16 etc.

The rows are labelled as follows: hours = manual entry, bank hols = bank holidays between two dates (elsewhere on sheet), hours in bank = total hours that would be worked on bank holidays, is a work day = if(hours="0","0","1").

The cell I want would be somewhere below these, but it wouldn't particularly matter as it will be hidden anyway.

Is there a way to work out whether all the values in the manual input "hours" are equal while ignoring all those in the range if they equal 0 (or are blank).

From this I am wanting to display "Days" if they are the same, else show "hours".

I'm also aware that this may require a bit of VBA which I'm currently looking at, but it'd still be nice to get some feedback on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`=IF(COUNTIF(A1:E1,AVERAGEIFS(A1:E1,A1:E1,">"&0))=COUNTIF(A1:E1,">"&0),COUNTIF(A1:E1,">"&0)&" Days",SUM(A1:E1)&" Hours")`

Where the values are in **A1:E1**

EDIT: edited original formula, please use above corrected formula

Answer (score 0):

Say we want to test **A1** thru **A13**

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A1:A13<>"")/COUNTIF(A1:A13,A1:A13&""))=1,"Days","Hours")
```

blanks will be ignored.

Comment: That's not it unfortunately. It's displaying Hours no matter what values are in the input fields. I'm needing it to show hours if the non zeroes aren't equal

Comment: If we see your data, perhaps we can fix the formula.

Comment: I tried to initially but as I'm a new user I don't yet have enough rep to upload screenshots

Comment: My formula basically counts *unique* values and ignores blank cells.<br>If the count exceeds **1** then *Hours* will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are only checking one linear set of data IE:

HRS = 1

Bank Holiday Hrs = 1

Hrs in Bank = 1

then you can try

=IF(MOD(SUM(A2:C2),2),"days","hours")

Where A2:C2 are your rows with the data.
If this requires a unique check of actual hrs then it wont work with any values other than 1 or 0 of course.